# lazy loading outside command context error

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, alfresco, activiti

I am currently developping a java jee application using activiti as process engine and alfresco as ged.i am using mvc design pattern and micro services to make rest calls for the backend  project.I want to pass a list of ProcessInstances via the controller,but i got this error.

> Etat HTTP 500 - Could not write content: lazy loading outside command
>   context (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity["variableInstances"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: lazy loading
>   outside command context (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity["variableInstances"])

By the way the service works fine when i test it without rest call.
this is my controller:

```
@RestController 
public class CourriersArrivésController {
CourriersArrivésServices courriersArrivésServices;
@RequestMapping(value = "/listCourriersArrivés", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<ProcessInstance> getAllCourriers(){
courriersArrivésServices=new CourriersArrivésImpl();

List<ProcessInstance> listeCourrier = courriersArrivésServices.getListCourriersArrivées() ;
return listeCourrier ;
}
}
```